# Configurations of Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

MS Visual Studio 2012 default has two configuartions: Debug and Release. 
I write plugins for AutoCAD and BricsCAD. This code is the same, but using different libraries referenced.

I need to add new configurations: **DebugForAutoCAD** and **DebugForBricsCAD**. Each of this must to has own *references*, *default namespace*, *assembly name*, *output path* and *start external program* option.

If I change the references, these changes are applied to all configurations. I need that references were individual for each configuration. And other settings too.

Can I do it easy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is no user interface support in VS for this, but you can manually edit the project files like this:

```
<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DebugForAutoCad' ">
  <Reference Include="somref"/>
  <Reference Include="somotherref />
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DebugForAutoCad' ">
  <OutputPath>somePath<OutputPath/>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DebugForBricsCAD' ">
  <Reference Include="anohterRef"/>
</ItemGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'DebugForBricsCAD' ">
  <OutputPath>someOtherPath<OutputPath/>
</PropertyGroup>
```

and so on. If you have to do this for multiple projects, I highly suggest putting everything common in a seperate file and use it in each project file using `Import`.

Comment: I use this method to build for different versions of AutoCAD, even changing framework versions. Using one project means you can't / don't forget to add linked code files to the other projects. I found VS can refactor wildcard references in a project file into the individual files. [Resharper 7 complains about ambiguous references](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-329698) in the code when it finds AcCoreMgd.dll and you then switch to a version that doesn't use it but it all builds just fine. Suspending R# makes the errors go away. I'm using C# and not C++ so your mileage may vary.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating separate projects for each AutoCAD and Bricscad target, then simply share source files among all projects. This way the projects each have their own references, and use the standard Release and Debug configurations that can be easily managed in the UI. It's a bit dated, but I blogged in 2007 about this:
http://otb.manusoft.com/2007/06/visual-studio-build-configuration-tip.htm